# How to download private image (locally) using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab, registry

This is my first time posting on here so apologies in advance if my question is quite broad or not structured well
I have recently set-up my ci/cd pipeline and created my container registry successfully. This is my gitlab-ci.yml file

[gitlab-ci.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mztzj.png)

My current goal is to download the private image (Locally) created on GitLab using docker-compose . I am kind of lost as to what this process looks like . Any help will be much appreciated even if its referencing documentation .

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You seem to have attached an image to the question instead of your YAML file.  Can you edit the question to include the text of the YAML directly in the question, not as an image and not behind a link?

Answer (score 1):

In your docker-compose file you have to write the full image name. but first you have to login to that registry

`docker login  <<docker-registry>>`
Enter your username and password for that docker-registry.

Now if you run this command it should work
`docker pull <<docker-registry>>/yourImage`

and this is docker-copmose example

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgresql:
    image: <<docker-rigstry>>/postgres:9.11
    container_name: pg-docker
    ports:
      - "5400:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=docker
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker
    volumes:
      - ./postgres.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    restart: always
```